# GET request works but POST returns 404

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post some data to a php page from javascript (both are on the same domain just in different folders)
I am using jquery ajax to send my request.
If I use a GET request everything is working fine but when I switch to POST I get a 404 response.

My js:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: myurl,
  data: {html: 'hello', name: 'bob'},
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

My php:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $html = $_POST['html'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $html . ' ' . $name;
}
```

Comment: are you sure about the url?

Comment: it's not about `GET` or `POST`, the problem should be in URL only.

Comment: The url is fine, i manage to complete the request using a GET request and print out the same parameters from the $_GET variable, only when i use POST i get the 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently The problem was with the environment i was using. I was trying to send the request in a testing sub-domain which wasn't public, once i moved the code to my production environment, the request went through just fine.
I can't really pinpoint the exact reason it didn't work but that's the only difference between the two environments.